# Selecting record from comboBox populated by mysql

Tags: c#

I have a query that populates a comboBox and depanding on the selection from the comboBox pass the value to another query.

The code I have so far is:

```
    MySqlCommand SelectCommandAirport = new MySqlCommand("SELECT AirportName, DataTable  FROM    AirportList;", myConnAirport);
MySqlDataReader myAirportReader;
    myConnAirport.Open();

    myAirportReader = SelectCommandAirport.ExecuteReader();
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
    dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("AirportName"));
    dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("DataTable"));
    comboBox1.DataSource = dataTable;
    comboBox1.ValueMember = "AirportName";
    comboBox1.DisplayMember = "DataTable";
try
    {
       while (myAirportReader.Read())
       {
          DataRow row = dataTable.NewRow();
          row["AirportName"] = myAirportReader[1];
          row["DataTable"] = myAirportReader[0];
          dataTable.Rows.Add(row);

          SelectAirport.sAirport = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
       }
     }
 catch (Exception ex)
     {
     MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
     }
```

Then I have a seond query that should use the result of the comboBox selection as a variable for the second query.

```
    string airportid;
    airportid = SelectAirport.sAirport;
    MySqlCommand SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand("SELECT ArriveDepart, Flight, FlightDate, ScheduledTime, IATALookup, Terminal, RemarkswithTime, Logo   FROM '" + airportid + "' WHERE Flight = '" + this.flightno_txt.Text + "';", myConnFlight);
```

When I run the code I get an SQL error that says "System.Data.DataRowView WHERE Flight =".

Becuse this is not working I can assume that the code is in correct. Can anyone see where I am going wrong.

Many thanks in advance.

DCJ

When I run the code I get an SQL error that shows the content

Comment: Is airportID the name of your table? Do you have each airport in its own table? That's how the query is written right now.

Answer (score 0):

This is called a cascading dropdown - the prime example is "pick your country, then pick your province"

ASP.Net now provides a feature to make this MUCH easier than it was. If you can't use this feature though, what you are already doing is pretty much correct - pick one, then submit to the next query and load the box from that.

This is from the ASP.Net AJAX Library...
http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx

ALSO, you have extra work in your code sample. When you run the ExecuteReader command, it returns a DataReader object, which can be bound directly to your Control, like this...

```
MySqlCommand SelectCommandAirport = new MySqlCommand("SELECT AirportName, DataTable  FROM    AirportList;", myConnAirport);

MySqlDataReader myAirportReader;
myConnAirport.Open();

myAirportReader = SelectCommandAirport.ExecuteReader();
comboBox1.DataSource = dataTable;
comboBox1.ValueMember = "AirportName";
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "DataTable";
comboBox1.DataBind();
```

That tends to work better than creating items and copying them into your combobox.

I suspect that your SQL error is because you're treating the AirportName as a table name, not a data value. So, your query should be more like this (I like to use String.Format to more clearly indicate parameter positions within the string):

```
String.Format("SELECT ArriveDepart, Flight, FlightDate, ScheduledTime, IATALookup,
    Terminal, RemarkswithTime, Logo  
    FROM AIRPORT_TABLE WHERE AirportName = '{0}'
         AND Flight = {1}", airportId, flightno_txt.Text)
```

And you need to replace AIRPORT_TABLE with the actual name of your table, if this is really the way it's supposed to work. Just a guess.